# JWT token is invaild

Tags: node.js, jwt

I use JWT for auth.
The auth will be a middleware:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.header("auth-token");
    if (!token) return res.status(401).send("Missing token. Access denied");

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.jwtKey);
        req.user = decoded;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).send('Invalid token.');
    }
};
```

now when I get an token and use it in header "auth-token" and making a get or post request with the auth middleware its allways gives me "**JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature**"

I use the middleware like this:

```
router.get('/:id', auth, async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({
        _id: req.params.id,
    });
    if (!user) return res.status(404).send('User not found');
    res.send(user);
})
```

here is where the token is generated

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {

    //check for validation errors
    const { error } = validate(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (!user) return res.status(404).send("Invalid email or password");

    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (!validPassword) return res.status(400).send("Invalid email or password");

    res.json({ token: user.generateAuthToken(), status: "User is logged in" })
});


const validate = (req) => {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        email: Joi.string().min(6).max(255).email().required(),
        password: Joi.string().min(6).max(255).required(),
    });
    return schema.validate(req);
};


module.exports = router;
```

You can see the auth middleware is used when I make the request GET
At JWT.io debugger when I put the token its says its ok... so whats worng?

Comment: Please make sure you are using the same secret at the time of signing and decoding.

Comment: this usually means you are not sending correct token. Share the code where you generate the token

Comment: I updated the question with the code

Answer (score 0):

So I sloved the issue, I had mistake with the key I decoded and key I veryfied.